# Django-Postgres WHERE query using varchar_pattern_ops index instead of pkey index

Tags: django, postgresql, postgresql-9.5, database-indexes, django-1.9

I have a Django-Postgres setup with this table -

```
class User(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True)
```

Running the migration creates two indexes on the field (which is what Django automatically does as I checked from running `sqlmigrate`) - one index for pkey and one for `varchar_pattern_ops` -

```
\d+ "user";

Column|            Type          | Modifiers | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id   |  character varying(255)  | not null  | extended |              | 

Indexes:
"user_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
"user_id_90845346_like" btree (id varchar_pattern_ops)
```

As I understand it, if I run this query

```
select * from "user" where id='id1234';
```

it should use `user_pkey`. Instead it uses `user_id_90845346_like`.

```
explain analyze select * from "user" where id='id1234';

 Index Scan using "user_id_90845346_like" on "user"  (cost=0.41..8.43 rows=1 width=770) (actual time=0.033..0.0
33 rows=0 loops=1)
   Index Cond: ((id)::text = 'id1234'::text)
 Planning time: 1.335 ms
 Execution time: 0.072 ms
(4 rows)
```

I also don't see any option to force Postgres to use an index, but what I actually want to know is why an `=` search doesn't use the primary key. Shouldn't `like text%` searches use the `varchar_pattern_ops` index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The postgres driver is always going to opt for the `varchar_pattern_ops` index if it exists in cases where the column you're indexing on is a varchar column or some variant thereof. In simple terms, because your column that you're indexing on holds strings, the driver will opt for the index that works best with strings when it's available. If you stored the primary keys as integers instead, the driver would use the `btree` index.